# Interpretation of sign switch of marginal effect

Tags: marginal-effect

I have calculated marginal effects for my problem. How do I interpret aswitch of the sign of the marginal effect (see plot).

For example, when I want to answer a question like the following.

Does the effect of z on y decreases if x increases?

Furthermore, I know that z has a positive effect on y.

Do I say that the effect of z on y decreases for increasing x values and becomes negative for very big values of x or what do I say. My problem is that it decreases until 0 and then the absolute value of the marginal effect increases again.

[image: Plot of marginal effect]

Comment: It seems that x and z has interaction on the y. How does your model model lokk like?

Comment: My derive my model with `glm(y ~ x  + z + x*z)` in R

Comment: Based on the model you fit, I still cannot understand your graph.

Comment: The graph shows that the marginal effect of z on y decreases when x increases. But I do not know what to say when the marginal effect gets negative.